# How to get bukkit version?

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to use reflect in my plugin.

But I don't know how to get bukkit, or NMS versions like v1_8_R1, v1_7_R4 and so on.

Is there any way to get this kind of things? Or I need to use a switch to detect it using Bukkit.getVerion(); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get package name of any NMS or CB class.

Example below takes normal bukkit server instance `plugin.getServer()` and gets the class which is CraftServer and reads the version from package.

```
public static String getVersion(Server server) {
    final String packageName = server.getClass().getPackage().getName();

    return packageName.substring(packageName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this set of Methods to determine which version or if it is a newer version:

```
public static boolean isMC110(){
    return Bukkit.getBukkitVersion().contains("1.10");
}

public static boolean isMC19(){
    return Bukkit.getBukkitVersion().contains("1.9");
}

public static boolean isMC18(){
    return Bukkit.getBukkitVersion().contains("1.8");
}

public static boolean isMC17(){
    return Bukkit.getBukkitVersion().contains("1.7");
}

public static boolean isMC110OrNewer(){
    if (isMC110()) 
        return true;
    else if (isMC19()||isMC18()||isMC17())
        return false;
    return true;
}

public static boolean isMC19OrNewer(){
    if (isMC19()) 
        return true;
    else if (isMC18()||isMC17())
        return false;
    return true;
}

public static boolean isMC18OrNewer(){
    if (isMC18()) 
        return true;
    else if (isMC17())
        return false;
    return true;
}
```